# Can't start hosted network

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

In CMD I enter this command `netsh wlan start hostednetwork`
It says:

> The hosted network couldn't be started. The group or resource is not
>   in the correct state to perform the requested opera tion.

I'm using Windows 7, Atheros AR5B95 Wireless card. This card supports Hosted Network, I checked it in CMD.
Can't use any software to create hotspot because of this problem. I tried every solutio I could on the internet.
The same thing happens on my sister's laptop. My friend doesn't have those problems. I have no idea what to do.

Both wifi card and Microsoft virtual miniport adapter are enabled and running fine.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the mode is set to allow as in the below example before you run the start command.

> netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=ssidOfUrChoice
>   key=keyOfUrChoice

and after that run the command

> netsh wlan start hostednetwork

.

Also once the usage is over with the Miniport adapter connection, it is a good practise to stop it using the following command.

netsh wlan stop hostednetwork

Comment: I forgot to say that I already tried that. Doesn't work

Comment: OK and you also have the MS hotfix installed?

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2496820

Comment: Yep, it doesn't work. Right now I can't even detect any wireless networks even with my USB wireless adapter installed

Comment: I solved my problem by reinstalling windows